# how to sum particular vectors within a dataset ignoring NA values in R

Tags: r

Say I have a dataset, `test`:

```
a<- c(NA,1,2)
b<- c(1,NA,2)
c<- c('not','relevant','vector')
test<-data.frame(a,b,c)
```

I want to sum the columns `test$a` and `test$b`, however

`test$a + test$b`
returns:

```
[1] NA NA  4
```

I want it to return:

```
[1] 1 1  4
```

the `rowSums` command with `na.rm=T` setting will not work, because of the 3rd vector. I do not want to subset my particular columns, as this is a simple case of a much larger problem.

Comment: You don't want this? `rowSums(cbind(test$a,test$b), na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @RonakShah that can work!

Comment: or more concise `rowSums(test[,1:2], na.rm=T)`

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by not wanting to subset the columns. That seems like the easiest way to go about this problem, even if it's a scaled down version. If you're worried about specifying which columns to include, you could just add a line that checks if a column is numeric or not and use that as an index. Something like `good_cols <- which(sapply(test, class) == "numeric"); rowSums(test[, good_cols], na.rm = T)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rowSums(cbind(test$a,test$b), na.rm=TRUE)

#[1] 1 1 4
```

Or as per @Colonel Beauvel's comment there is no need for `cbind` here. You can directly use -

```
rowSums(test[,1:2], na.rm=T)

#[1] 1 1 4
```

Comment: you should probably correct your answer according to @colonel beauvel's comment above. why extract columns of a dataframe just to stick them back together via `cbind`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sum of all the columns that are numeric do:

```
rowSums(test[,sapply(test,is.numeric)],na.rm = T)

[1] 1 1 4
```

I know that this subsets all columns that are numeric, but if you have 50 numeric columns and several other non-numeric then doing `test$col1 + test$col2 + ...` is not very efficient.

Comment: It is effective, just not efficient.